# Windows File Audit Programmatically

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I want to enable file auditing on a specific set of a files using a script on Windows systems. I have tried to use Python Watchdog to accomplish this, but this does not capture read events. I tried to look into Python Watchdog documentation, but haven't found a way to capture read events.

Any suggestions here?